# Send different data through AJAX call depending on if form was submitted or div was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a function called `search` and it is called through either a div being clicked or a form being submitted.

When the div is clicked, the `id` of it is send as data through the AJAX call. However what I want to do is if the form is submitted, send the inputted data through the AJAX call.

I thought about having two functions and AJAX calls, however I feel this is unnecessary and there must be a simple solution.

```
<div id="12" class="question"></div>
<div id="24" class="question"></div>
<div id="11" class="question"></div>

<form id="question" method="post">
<input type="text" name="enter" id="enter">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<script>
$(".question").click(search);
$("form#question").submit(search);

function search() {
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "sending.php",
      data: "example=" + this.id,
      success: function(data) {
         console.log(data);
      }
   });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check what you click with `is` function:

```
var isDiv = $( this ).is( "div" );
// or 
// var isForm = $( this ).is( "form" );
```

And then decide what to send:

```
data: isDiv ? ("example=" + this.id) : $( this ).serialize(),
```

Simplified:

```
data: $( this ).is( "div" ) ? ("example=" + this.id) : $( this ).serialize(),
```

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble understanding this. If it isn't a div, how would I then get the value of the inputted text?

Comment: `serialize()` function serializes all form's inputs to a string. You can rename your input to `example` and serialized string will be `example=VALUE OF INPUT`

Answer (score 0):

This first thing I added was `event.preventDefault();` in order to make sure that the HTML-page stays in the browser, even when pressing button *submit*.

Using `var enter = $("form#question input#enter").val();` you can retrieve the value of field *enter*. If a div is clicked the value is null.

In the ajax-call I use javascript-object with fields *id* and *name* and use it as data-parameter.

Please note that you should put javascript code in a separate file. Avoiding inline javascript makes it easier to prevent **XSS**. Read [1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) and [2](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/).

[See Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/7MECxY1b29cYYr3w017G?p=preview)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".question").click(search);
$("form#question").submit(search);

function search(event) {

  // prevents form submission
  event.preventDefault();

  var id = this.id;
  var enter = $("form#question input#enter").val();

   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "sending.php",
      data: {
        'id': id,
        'enter': enter
      },
      success: function(data) {
         console.log(data);
      }
   });
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, This will help you sure

```
<div id="12" class="question">12</div>
<div id="24" class="question">24</div>
<div id="11" class="question">11</div>

<form id="question" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="enter" id="enter">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<script>
    $(document).on('click','.question',function(){
        console.log($("input[name='enter']").val($(this).attr('id')));
        $("#question").submit();
    });
</script>
```